# Who is the master of dreams in Esther 4:1 (Rashi)?

Tags: rashi, megillat-esther, dream

Rashi on Esther 4:1 indicates that

> **The Master of Dreams** told him that the celestial beings had concurred about it, because they had prostrated themselves to an image in the days of Nebuchadnezzar and because they had enjoyed Ahasuerus’s feast.

I would like to know "The Master of Dreams" is referring to? Is it a person, an angel, something/someone else?

Answer (score 3):

[Rashi in Sanhedrin 30a](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01004.html#HtmpReportNum0058_L2) says:

> **בעל החלום**. שר המראה חלומות בלילה

The Master of Dreams is some sort of celestial messenger in charge of what you see when you dream.

On the other hand, Chazal [(Brachot 55b)](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00878.html#HtmpReportNum0107_L2)  knew that you tend to dream about what you thought about during the day.

> אין מראין לו לאדם אלא מהרהורי לבו

So possibly this  Master of Dreams is only in charge of dreams that have a special meaning - a minor prophecy - and not all dreams.

The Gemara in [Brachot 55b](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00878.html#HtmpReportNum0107_L2) mentions that some dreams are "brought/sent" by and angel, and some by a Shed (demon?).

> כאן ע''י מלאך כאן ע''י שד